# развернуть связный список на python

Tags: python, python-3.x, односвязный-список

добрый день, не могли бы подсказать, как можно развернуть связный список? Нужно на python'e..

```
from typing import Iterable

class LinkedListNode:

    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data
        self.next = None  # type: LinkedListNode

    def link(self, node: 'LinkedListNode') -> None:
        self.next = node


class LinkedList:

    def __init__(self, values: Iterable):
        previous = None
        self.head = None
        for value in values:
            current = LinkedListNode(value)
            if previous:
                previous.link(current)
            self.head = self.head or current
            previous = current

    def __iter__(self):
        current = self.head
        while current:
            yield current.data
            current = current.next

    def reverse(self) -> None:
        print("развернуть список")
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Чтобы обратить порядок элементов в связном списке за линейное время (`O(n)`), не требуется много кода:

```
def reverse_list(head, tail=None):
    while head:
        head.next, tail, head = tail, head, head.next
    return tail
```

Код в цикле отсекает голову списка (head/car), добавляя к ней хвост (tail) — `head.next = tail` часть. Затем хвост наращивается (новый хвост указывает на только что отсечённую голову с добавленным старым хвостом) — `tail = head` часть. Остаток списка (head.next/cdr) становится новой головой (head) — `head = head.next` часть. Повторяем до конца списка — `while head` часть.

Чтобы лучше понять код, [рекомендую по шагам пройти (кнопка <kbd>Next></kbd>)](http://pythontutor.com/visualize.html#code=%23!/usr/bin/env%20python%0A%22%22%22Reverse%20linked%20list.%22%22%22%0A%0A%0Aclass%20Node%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%22%22%22Linked%20list%20is%20either%20None%20or%20a%20value%20and%20a%20link%20to%20the%20next%20list.%22%22%22%0A%0A%20%20%20%20def%20__init__%28self,%20data,%20next%3DNone%29%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20self.data%20%3D%20data%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20self.next%20%3D%20next%0A%0A%0Ahead%20%3D%20Node%281,%20Node%282,%20Node%283,%20Node%284%29%29%29%29%0A%0A%0Adef%20print_list%28head,%20end%3D%27%5Cn%27%29%3A%0A%20%20%20%20while%20head%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20print%28head.data,%20end%3D%27%20-%3E%20%27%20if%20head.next%20else%20%27%27%29%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20head%20%3D%20head.next%0A%20%20%20%20print%28end%3Dend%29%0A%0A%0Aprint_list%28head%29%0A%0A%0Adef%20reverse_list%28head,%20tail%3DNone%29%3A%0A%20%20%20%20while%20head%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20head.next,%20tail,%20head%20%3D%20tail,%20head,%20head.next%0A%20%20%20%20return%20tail%0A%0A%0Aprint_list%28reverse_list%28head%29%29&cumulative=false&curInstr=39&heapPrimitives=false&mode=display&origin=opt-frontend.js&py=3&rawInputLstJSON=%5B%5D&textReferences=false), обращая внимание на значения head, tail локальных переменных в `reverse_list()` функции.

В Питоне, объекты в правой части `=` конструкции вычисляются до того как фактическое присваивание происходит, которое затем  выполняется слева направо (например, нельзя поменять местами `head.next, head` пару. Так как `head.next`, идущий после `head` в левой части присваивания, обращался бы уже к новой изменённой голове списка).

Полный пример:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
"""Reverse linked list."""


class Node:
    """Linked list is either None or a value and a link to the next list."""

    def __init__(self, data, next=None):
        self.data = data
        self.next = next


head = Node(1, Node(2, Node(3, Node(4))))


def print_list(head, end='\n'):
    while head:
        print(head.data, end=' -> ' if head.next else '')
        head = head.next
    print(end=end)


print_list(head)


def reverse_list(head, tail=None):
    while head:
        head.next, tail, head = tail, head, head.next
    return tail


print_list(reverse_list(head))
```

[Результат](http://ideone.com/N0uG10):

```
1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4
4 -> 3 -> 2 -> 1
```

По сути Питон-код это перевод из Lisp [алгоритма](https://repl.it/J8zZ/1):

```lisp
(define reverse-list (lambda (head tail)
  (if (null? head)
      tail
      (reverse-list (cdr head) (cons (car head) tail)))))
        
(reverse-list '(1 2 3 4) '())   
; -> (4 3 2 1)
```