# Смена мест минимального и максимального значений в списке

Tags: python, алгоритм, python-3.x

У меня есть код, который создает массив и 20 случайных элементов. Нужно найти больший и меньший элементы и поменять их местами.

Вот код:

```
from random import randint

numbers = []

for i in range(20):
    numbers.append(randint(0, 20))
```

Comment: Как быть если числа повторяются?

Comment: В чем проблема - найти позиции минимума и максимума или провести их смену?

Comment: @mkkik [ответ Alban](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/698813/23044) показывает, что можно ещё ошибиться при комбинации решений (по отдельности код для поиска экстремумов и  код для смены работали бы)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Например так:

```
>>> lst = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
>>> lst[lst.index(max(lst))], lst[lst.index(min(lst))] = lst[lst.index(min(lst))], lst[lst.index(max(lst))]
>>> lst
[10, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 1]
```

**Объяснение**:

сначала мы берем максимальный элемент:

```
>>> lst = [1, 2, 3]
>>> max_element = max(lst)
>>> max_element
3
```

далее находим его индекс:

```
>>> lst.index(max_element)
2
```

По аналогии с минимальным, после этого меняем местами.

Но когда индекс минимального элемента > индекса максимального работать не будет, в таком случае поступим так:

```
>>> def getIndex(array):
...     imin = array.index(min(array))
...     imax = array.index(max(array))
...     if imin > imax:
...             return imin, imax
...     return imax, imin
>>> lst
[5, 4, 1]
>>> lst[getIndex(lst)[0]], lst[getIndex(lst)[1]] = lst[getIndex(lst)[1]], lst[getIndex(lst)[0]]
>>> lst
[1, 4, 5]
>>> lst[getIndex(lst)[0]], lst[getIndex(lst)[1]] = lst[getIndex(lst)[1]], lst[getIndex(lst)[0]]
>>> lst
[5, 4, 1]
```

Comment: А можно проще?)

Comment: @Михаил а что тут сложного? Мы берем индекс максимального элемента списка, потом минимального, меняем местами, все.

Comment: @Михаил добавил объяснение

Comment: У вас упорядоченные данные, поэтому решение работает. Если же позиция минимума выше позиции максимума, то работать не будет. https://repl.it/Jm7G/1

Comment: @mkkik при каком массиве не будет работать можно узнать ?

Comment: @Alban если массив неупорядочен и выполняется условие, о котором выше написал. Посмотрите выполнение по ссылке.

Comment: @mkkik лол, и правда

Comment: @mkkik но это не логично. почему так происходит?

Comment: На момент вычисления выражения в индексе `lst.index(max(lst))` (правая часть выражения) уже произошло присвоение `lst[lst.index(min(lst))]`. Я так понял, может, кто объяснит правильно.

Comment: @mkkik в этом вся суть свапинга, не должно же

Comment: Но не в случае, если перед присвоением надо выполнить вычисление, видимо.

Comment: @mkkik обновил ответ

Comment: @mkkik правая часть вычисляется до того как присваивание происходит, но само присваивание по порядку слева направо происходит: второй lst.index() слева вызывается уже для изменённого списка. Чтобы понимание проверить, посмотрите к примеру [как связный список можно в Питоне обратить с помощью присваивания в цикле](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/694197/23044)

Comment: Всей этой пляски с getIndex() можно избежать , если найти индексы до присваивания, как показано в моём ответе.

Comment: @jfs да, я перепутал, имел в виду вычисление в левой части.

Answer (score 3):

Чтобы поменять местами элементы в списке `L` с индексами `i`, `j` в Питоне:

```
L[i], L[j] = L[j], L[i]
```

Чтобы найти индексы, на которых минимальный, максимальный элементы находятся:

```
i, j = [f(range(len(L)), key=L.__getitem__) for f in [min, max]]
```

Выражение ищет места, соответствующие минимуму и максимуму значений из L, используя последовательность индексов (`range(len(L))`), с помощью `L.__getitem__` [специального метода](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/647069/23044), который реализует `L[index]` операцию в Питоне.

(Функции в Питоне являются обычными объектами: можно их в список положить, как пример показывает для min, max функций).

Если элементы могут повторяться, то переставляется только одна пара экстремумов. К примеру:

```
L = list("haha")  
swap_min_max(L)
print(*L)  # -> a h h a
```

([Что значит * (звёздочка) и ** двойная звёздочка в Питоне?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/594651/23044))

Только первые вхождения минимума и максимума поменялись местами.

Где:

```
def swap_min_max(L):
    i, j = [f(range(len(L)), key=L.__getitem__) for f in [min, max]]
    L[i], L[j] = L[j], L[i]
```