# Поменять местами ноды в односвязном списке

Tags: python, алгоритм, односвязный-список

Я застрял на применении односвязного списка. Проблема в том, что я не могу понять почему не меняются местами последний и предпоследние элементы списка.

```
class LinkedListNode:

def __init__(self, value: object, next_: None):
    self.value = value
    self.next_ = next_

class LinkedList:

"""
front - первый нод в списке
back - последний
size - размер, если больше 0
"""

def __init__(self) -> None:

    self.front = None
    self.back = None
    self.size = 0

def prepend(self, value):
    """
    Помещаем элемент в начало списка.

    >>> lnk = LinkedList()
    >>> lnk.prepend(0)
    >>> lnk.prepend(1)
    >>> print(lnk)
    1 -> 0 -> |
    """
    self.front = LinkedListNode(value, self.front)
    if self.back is None:
        self.back = self.front
    self.size += 1


def swap_front_back(self):
    """
    Меняем LinkedListNodes front и back для связного списка. 
   Не меняя значения и не создавая еще один связной список.

    >>> lnk = LinkedList()
    >>> lnk.prepend(3)
    >>> lnk.prepend(2)
    >>> lnk.prepend(1)
    >>> print(lnk)
    1 -> 2 -> 3 -> |
    >>> front_id = id(lnk.front)
    >>> back_id = id(lnk.back)
    >>> lnk.swap_front_back()
    >>> print(lnk)
    3 -> 2 -> 1 -> |
    >>> front_id == id(lnk.back)
    True
    >>> back_id == id(lnk.front)
    True
    """
    # Код нерабочий черновик

    element = self.front

    element.next = tmp.next

    while element.next != self.back:
        if element.next == self.back:
           element.next = element
    self.back.next = element.next
```

Comment: Вы хотите поменять местами последний и предпоследний элементы связного списка?

Comment: связанный вопрос: [развернуть связный список на python](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/694132/23044)

Comment: Здравствуйте! Что-то вроде того, но меняя определенные ноды! Как например : 1-2-3-4-5, после swap 5-2-3-4-1.

Comment: вы хотите поменять значения первого и последнего узлов или сами узлы?

Comment: Сами узлы, не меняя значения.  При значениях это легко сделать, но не меняя я залип на этой проблеме.

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы поменять первый и последний узлы в односвязном списке, можно три случая рассмотреть:

1. меньше двух узлов: вернуть список как есть
2. ровно два узла: поменять узлы местами
3. больше двух: сделать, чтобы последний узел указывал бы на второй узел, а предпоследний — на первый.

```py
def swap_first_last(head):
    if head and head.next: # at least two nodes
        ntl = next_to_last(head)
        last = ntl.next
        if ntl is head:  # exactly two nodes
            last.next, head.next, head = head, last.next, last
        else: # > 2
            last.next, head.next, ntl.next, head = head.next, last.next, head, last
    return head
```

где `next_to_last()` ищет предпоследний узел:

```py
def next_to_last(head):
    if not head or not head.next:
        raise ValueError("can't return the next to last node: the llist is too short")
    while head.next:
        node, head = head, head.next
    return node
```

Пример:

```py
>>> print_list((Node(1, Node(2, Node(3, Node(4))))))
1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4
>>> print_list(swap_first_last(Node(1, Node(2, Node(3, Node(4))))))
4 -> 2 -> 3 -> 1
```

где [`print_list()` и `Node` определены в ответе на похожий вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/694197/23044).

Это достаточно прямолинейное решение в лоб, возможно есть более элегантный подход.

Comment: Спасибо! Я сделал не вводя дополнительное значение, через loop, while self.front is not None. Спасибо еще раз за дополнительные варианты.