# Как работает l1, l2 = l2, l1 + l2 + 1? Почему переменные через запятую/повторяются?

Tags: python

Представлен следующий код:

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как питон вычисляет  эта часть: l1, l2 = l2, l1 + l2 + 1

```
n = int(input('PLease, type a number: '))

l1 = l2 = 1
l_n = []

for i in range(0, n + 1):
   if i > 1:
       l1, l2 = l2, l1 + l2 + 1
       l_n.append(l2)
   else:
       l_n.append(l2) 
print(l_n)
```

Comment: Справа от знака = кортеж из двух элементов, слева переменные через запятую, в которые будут запихнуты элементы этого кортежа по порядку. По-умному это называется распаковкой последовательности (кортежа)

Comment: @andreymal это верно, но стоит в форму ответа, а не комментария поместить.

Comment: @jfs в ответе хорошо смотрелся бы более подробный рассказ про распаковку (и про такой странный синтаксис кортежей), а мне лень

Comment: а можете, пожалуйста, объяснить почему переменные через запятую, а потом еще одна переменная повторяется

Comment: а почему синтаксис странный? это можно как-то проще записать?

Comment: чуть более сложное использование присваивания [развернуть связный список на python](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/694132/23044)

Answer (score 4):

1. В питоне есть такая структура данных, как кортеж. Она представляет из себя последовательность из нескольких элементов, и записывается как перечисление через запятую в круглых скобках:

   ```
   x = (1, 2, 3, 4)
   ```
2. Во многих случаях скобки можно не писать, и записывать без них.

   ```
   x = 1, 2, 3, 4
   # То же самое, что и в предыдущем примере
   ```
3. Если слева от равно написать кортеж переменных, а справа - кортеж из значений той же длины, то значения разложатся в соответствующие переменные.

   ```
   (x1, x2, x3, x4) = (1, 2, 3, 4)
   ```

   Здесь в каждую из переменных x1, x2, x3, x4 попадёт одно соответствующее число

   Без скобок тоже работает:

   ```
   x1, x2, x3, x4 = 1, 2, 3, 4
   # Получится то же самое
   ```
4. Справа от равно можно писать не только значения, но и переменные. Причём даже те же самые переменные, что и слева от равно.

   ```
   a, b = b, a
   ```

   Этот код поменяет значения переменных - то есть в `a` он положит то, что лежало в `b`, а в `b` положит то, что лежало в `a`
5. Можно не просто перекладывать значения. Справа от равно могут быть выражения.

   ```
   a, b, c = (a+b+c), (b+c), 0
   ```

   Этот код положит в `a` сумму всех трёх чисел, в `b` положит только сумму второго и третьего числа, а в `c` положит просто ноль.

Ну а теперь, когда вы всё это знаете, вам будет легко понять вашу строчку

```
l1, l2 = l2, l1 + l2 + 1
```

можно записать так:

```
 (l1, l2) = (l2, l1 + l2 + 1)
```

Этот код перекладывает значение из второй переменной в первую. А во вторую складывает сумму обоих переменных плюс 1.

Comment: cars=['bmw','cadillac','volvo','vw']
names=[['ivan','vw'],['fedor','bmw'],['petr','cadillac'],['adolf','bmw']]
result={}
for car in cars:
    for name in names:
        if name[1]==car:
            string={name[0]:car}
            result.update(string)
print(result) вы не могли бы подсказать как работает счетчик в этом коде?

Comment: @СветланаШарипова Лучше оформите отдельным вопросом. А то разбирать код, записанный в одну строчку не очень хочется. И уточните, что именно вы здесь понимаете под словом "счетчик".

Comment: Nit: 1- скобки нужны только для пустого кортежа `()`, иначе запятых достаточно. 2- Слева  (и конечно справа) от присваивания могут быть более сложные конструкции, к примеру: `*L, [d, k] = d[k], L[:] = [], ({},())`